# How to avoid skipping items in a list in zsh?

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, zsh

I am using `zsh` on Mac. I created a list `subjects` of say 25 items in that list.
Now, I would like to run all possible pairwise comparisons between the items in the list, e.g., `subject1` vs. `subject2`, but without running repeated measurements (such as subject1 vs. subject2 *and* subject2 vs subject1) Here is my code for this task:

```
subjects=(Subject1 Subject2 Subject4 Subject5 Subject6 Subject7 Subject8 Subject9 Subject10 Subject11 Subject12 Subject13 Subject14 Subject15 Subject16 Subject17 Subject18 Subject19 Subject20 Subject22 Subject23 Subject24 Subject25)
for i in $subjects
do
for j in $subjects
do
if [[ $i < $j ]]
then
echo "Processing pair $i - $j ..."
fi
done
done
```

The problem is that `zsh` skips the subjects from `subject10` to `subject19` and directly jumps to `subject20` after comparing `subject1` vs. `subject9`.
Where is the flaw in my code?

Comment: Note that `Subject10` is less than `Subject2` in the default collating order, because the code for `1` is smaller thant the code for `2`.

Answer (score 0):

I would not iterate over the arrays, but over the array indices, which allows us to use numeric comparision:

```
for i in {1..#$subjects}
do
  for j in {1..#$subjects}
  do
    if ((i < j))
    then
      echo Processing pair $subjects[i] and $subjects[j]
    fi
  done
done
```